# Cannot convert datetime values to a necessary format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am struggling with datetime format... This is my dataframe in pandas:

```
Datetime             Date        Field
2020-01-12 00:00:00  2020-12-01  6.543916
2020-01-12 00:10:00  2020-12-01  6.505547
2020-01-12 00:20:00  2020-12-01  7.047578
2020-01-12 00:30:00  2020-12-01  6.070998
2020-01-12 00:40:00  2020-12-01  6.452112
```

**df.dtypes**

```
Datetime                       object
Date                   datetime64[ns]
Field                         float64
```

I need to convert `Datetime` to datetime64 and swap months with days to get values in the format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, e.g. `2020-12-01 00:00:00`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"])
df["Datetime"] = df["Datetime"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Still I get the same dataframe as shown above...

Comment: use `df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S").dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll get what you want with `"%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S"` instead of `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` on your last line.

**EDIT:** Or better even, simply replace the last 2 lines of your code by the following:

```py
df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], format="%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
```

That way you won't get a `ParserError: month must be in 1..12` from `pd.to_datetime` in the case where your `Datetime` column contains something like `"2020-30-12 00:00:00"`

Answer (score 0):

Consider placing the parameter "errors":

```
df["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"], errors='coerce')
```

See if it helps you!